# Access the "stream_h264_ld_url" field of a video on Dailymotion API

Tags: dailymotion-api

I'm trying to access the field "stream_h264_ld_url" for a video on the Dailymotion API with this code:

```
    $dm = new \Dailymotion();

    $dm->setGrantType(
        \Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD,
        'xxxx',
        'xxxx',
        ['manage_videos'],
        [
            'username' => 'xxxx',
            'password' => 'xxxx',
        ]
    );

    $res = $dm->get(
        '/video/xxxx',
        [
            'fields' => ['id', 'stream_h264_ld_url']
        ]
    );
```

This returns: `Insufficient rights for the fields' parameter of route GET /video/<id>' with value stream_h264_ld_url'. Required roles: can-read-video-streams, can-read-my-video-streams.`

With the same code and auth I can acess the "stream_h264_hq_url" or "stream_h264_hd_url" for the same video (those fields are just a higher resolution).

Do I need different rights to access a lower resolution stream of a video ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message it seems that `stream_h264_ld_url` needs specific API right which is not given by default. If you really need an access to this field, you can contact your content manager or directly our support: [Help center](https://faq.dailymotion.com/hc/fr/requests/new?ticket_form_id=39467#new-request)

We will double check the roles needed for the low video qualities to maybe be less restrictive